# How to make "big steps" while auto-filling Google Sheets cells?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

If I pull down cells with `=A2`, it will be replaced by `=A3`, `=A4`, `=A5`...

If I pull down cells with formula `=SMALL(C66:C89, 1)`, it will be replaced by `=SMALL(C67:C90, 1)`, `=SMALL(C68:C91, 1)`, `=SMALL(C69:C92, 1)`...

---

But I need to make bigger, 24-cell steps, that's example:
`=SMALL (C66:C89, 1)`, `=SMALL (C90:C113, 1)`, `=SMALL (C114:137, 1)`...

---

What an easiest way to do that automatic?

Comment: If you shared a sample sheet, theres a very good chance that those 24-cell steps could be implied from the logic of your sheet.  it sounds like you want the lowest value "per section".  If those sections can be implied by other parts of the sheet, everything could probably just be in one query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this and drag down:

```
=SMALL(INDIRECT("C"&66+(ROW(A1)-1)*24&":C"&89+(ROW(A1)-1)*24); 1)
```

Comment: European users can change "," to ";" to make it work